# Get item at position "x" on Iterable class

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, iterator

I am creating an iterable class, and it works using a for loop like so:

```
for(let i of myClassInstance) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

However if I would like to grab an item at an index like so, I get `undefined`:

```
console.log(myClassInstance[2])
```

What can I do get the item from the class? Here is the iterator on my class, do I need something else to make this work?

```
class myClass {
  public [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let items = this._items
    let pointer = 0
    return {
      next(): IteratorResult<T> {
        if (pointer < items.length) {
          return { done: false, value: items[pointer++] }
        }
        return { done: true, value: items[items.length - 1] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why not add a method `item(index)` and use it?  Not sure if you can create index properties in js

Comment: I could, I was just hoping that I could do it that way

Comment: Maybe the closest thing is [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control)?  That's ES6 tho

Comment: Consider extending Array. `class MyClass extends Array {...}`

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do get the item from the class?

To use an array index, convert to an array:

```
console.log(Array.from(myClassInstance)[2]);
```